# Affordable hops in Europe

Tags: beer, hops

Where can I find affordable hops in Europe (Belgium, France or Hungary would be best)?

Comment: Define "affordable". Are internet prices too high for you? Aren't you looking for specific tastes and aromas?

Comment: I'm flagging this for being unclear as to what is being asked. Sourcing a local home brewer shop may also very easily be off topic.

Comment: In some parts of the world hops is not a commodity, like you walk out your apartment and there you go, a local home brewer shop. My question was where can I find affordable (good priced) hops, which are the main webshops where I can buy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest provider of homebrew supplies in Europe is brouwland.com. They are located in Beverlo, Belgium and are a supplier for nearly every online retailer in continental Europe.

Most online retailers I have tried to use charge fairly hefty shipping fees on international parcels, so depending on where you live (or where you want your hops shipped to), you may have to worry more about transport costs than the hops pricing.

Brouwland does sell discount (read: close to expiry date) hops by the 100g, 250g and kg, usually for up to 50% off.  If you want them shipped to France, it may be worth it.  If you want them shipped to Romania (eu sunt in Romania) it will not be worth the trouble.

If you are in Romania, there is a Brouwland distributor in Bucuresti ([fabrica-de-bere.ro](http://www.fabrica-de-bere.ro)).  His prices are decent (10-25 lei/100g depending on the type of hop) and shipping is not as extravagant as with other retailers.  Plus you'll get your hops by curier within 48 hours (weekday orders).

If you are anywhere else in continental Europe, you can check [Brouwland's distributor listings](https://www.brouwland.com/en/distributors) (many are in local languages, so get Google Translate ready) for the closest and cheapest shipping options for you.